# in vi, how can I extract the filename portion from a buffered word?

Tags: vim, filenames, vi

in vi, for example, I want to change a line

from

```
\cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_ e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkid.h
```

to

```
\cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/blkid.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkid.h
```

I have many such lines only with different filenames at the end.
I want to use command like (for a block using marker from 'a to .)

```
:'a,.s/\\cp \(.*\) \(.*\)/\\cp \1?? \2
```

?? should be 'the filename part of buffered word \2'

Is there any expression?(like `\2:filename` ?) I know in csh there is such function but I want to use something like that in vi.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `:s` cmd:

```
s#\v(BOX_)(.*/([^/]*))*#\1/\3\2#
```

in fact, in normal mode you can do this on that line:

```
$F/yg_gEp
```

record it as macro (or with `:normal` cmd) if you want to do it many times.